# Remove columns starting with same special character in a csv file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

My csv file has below columns:
AFM_reversal_indicator,Alert_Message,axiom_key,_timediff,player,__mv_Splunk_Alert_Id,__mv_nbr_plastic,__mv_code_acct_stat_demo.

I want to remove columns starting with "__mv".
I saw some posts where **pandas** are used to filter out columns.
Is it possible to do it using **csv** module in python, If yes how ?
Also, with Pandas what regex should I give:

```
df.filter(regex='')
df.to_csv(output_file_path)
```

P.S I am using python3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `.filter` for that. You can just find out which are those columns and then drop them from the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataframe (In our case create a dummy one with your columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["AFM_reversal_indicator", "Alert_Message,axiom_key", "_timediff,player",  "__mv_Splunk_Alert_Id", "__mv_nbr_plastic", "__mv_code_acct_stat_demo"])


# Get a list of all column names starting with "__mv"
mv_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("__mv")]

# Drop the columns
df = df.drop(columns=mv_columns)

# Save the updated dataframe to a CSV file
df.to_csv("cleaned_data.csv", index=False)
```

The `mv_columns` will iterate through the columns in your DataFrame and pick those that starts with "__mv". Then the `.drop` will just remove those from it.

If for some reason you want to use `csv` package only, then the solution might not be as elegant as with `pandas`. But here is a suggestion:

```
import csv

with open("original_data.csv", "r") as input_file, open("cleaned_data.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:

    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    header_row = next(reader)

    mv_columns = [col for col in header_row if col.startswith("__mv")]

    mv_column_indices = [header_row.index(col) for col in mv_columns]

    new_header_row = [col for col in header_row if col not in mv_columns]

    writer.writerow(new_header_row)

    for row in reader:
        new_row = [row[i] for i in range(len(row)) if i not in mv_column_indices]

        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

So, first, you read the first row that supposed to be your headers. With a similar logic as before, you find those columns that starts with "__mv" and then you get their indices. You write the new columns to your output file with those columns that don't exist to the "__mv" columns. Then you need to iterate through the rest of the CSV and remove those columns as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way we can do this via csv module ?? As pandas is not installed on our server.

Comment: @NamanAgarwal This is harder to test in my end, but it will probably work like the updated answer.

Comment: Vre Taso !?  ...

Answer (score 1):

You mean with standard python? You can use a list comprehension, e.g.

```
import csv

with open( 'data.csv', 'r' ) as f:
    DataGenerator = csv.reader( f )
    Header = next( DataGenerator )
    Header = [ Col.strip() for Col in Header ]
    Data = list( DataGenerator )
    if Data[-1] == []: del( Data[-1] )
    Data = [ [Row[i] for i in range( len( Header ) ) if not Header[i].startswith( "__mv" ) ] for Row in Data ]
    Header = [ Col for Col in Header if not Col.startswith( "__mv" ) ]
```

However, this is just a simple example. You'll probably have further things to consider, e.g. what type your csv columns have, whether you want to read all the data at once like I do here, or one-by-one from the generator to save on memory, etc.

You could also use the builtin `filter` command instead of the inner list comprehension.

Also, if you have numpy installed and you wanted something more 'numerical', you can always use "structured numpy arrays" (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). They're quite nice. (personally I prefer them to pandas anyway). Numpy also has its own csv-reading functions (see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-csv-files-with-numpy/)